# Get server ip behind load balancer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ip

I am trying to test which server serves a request however the setup has a load balancer between the server and client. How would i go about getting the IP address of the server rather than the load balancer. So far on the local machine i have tried although i know the middle two are for the client ip

```
  ip1 = @env['REMOTE_ADDR']           -- returns 127.0.0.1:3000
  ip2 = request.ip                    -- returns 10.0.2.2
  ip3 = request.host_with_port        -- returns 10.0.2.2
  ip4 = Socket.gethostname            -- returns precise32 (vm name)
```

Don't want to test this live until i am sure. Apologies if there's any detail lacking. If any more information is required just say the word.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the server sets an HTTP header with the information you can't.  That's the whole point of the load balancer, right?

Comment: I'm actually working on that approach now. The Cookie request header actually has the server id coded into it. I'm now trying to figure out how to get this information. Can get the header responses with response['Cache-Control'] but any and all attempts to get request header has failed. Any suggestions?